# AOKP Permission Manager?

Tags: permissions, aokp, builds

I am running Paranoid Android and love it, but it is hard on battery life. So I am looking at flashing back to AOKP.

In looking around, I've seen some vague references to a "Permission Management" ([such as mentioned here](http://aokp.co/blog/milestone-2-has-finally-arrived)) in the latest AOKP... but after googling for a couple days, can find no real details on it.

Is this something that is in the current stable builds of AOKP, or is just referring to the built-in one from Android 4.3 in the latest AOKP nightlies?

If anyone can point me to an article with a some good information on this feature and its current build status, I'd be very grateful. Been missing this functionality since LBE Privacy Guard died with Jelly Bean.

Mind you, I am aware of other options such as LBE, PDroid, XPrivacy. 
I'm looking specifically for more information about AOKP's permission management.

Thanks!

Comment: As you've tagged your question `permissions`: Did you check our [permissions tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info)? Also, the [privacy tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/privacy/info) might prove helpful. LBE and alternatives are also dealt with in [how to fake my personal information](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39463/16575).

Comment: I'm aware of other options. I've used LBE Privacy Guard - until the great Jelly Bean Crash. And used LBE Security, but that thing is MASSIVE overkill. I'm not so much asking about the options - I'm aware of PDroid and XPrivacy. I'm more asking specifically if anyone has any links to more details about the AOKP implementation beyond that small blurb linked.

Comment: Ah – sorry, then I misunderstood your question (I fully agree on the complete overkill of LBE SM and might add it's not even as reliable as LBE PG, from the readings on XDA). You might want to add that comment to the end of your question directly to make things clear so nobody misses that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've gone and flashed over to AOKP, so figured I'd update this with an answer about their **Permissions** management. It is found towards the bottom of the root **Settings** screen.

For each user-installed app it lets you turn off specific permissions. Essentially a very basic version of what LBE Privacy Guard used to let you do.

Some features that are missing:

- Ability to group by a permission (e.g. `Access Location`) and see all apps that use it with ability to disable them in this view
- Ability to change permissions on system apps (e.g. camera to disable geotagging completely)

So all in all, it's a nice feature, and more than available in most ROMs I know of without extensive modding/flashing of additional frameworks and things.

Potentially the 2nd item above could - at least in some cases - be gotten around by using something like ROM Toolbox to convert the system app to a user app... but I'm not sure what other ramifications doing so would have.

[image: AOKP Permissions Management]

Comment: UPDATE: I wound up installing the Xposed framework and the XPrivacy module. As nice as it is having it baked into the ROM, the one built in to AOKP is very limited and doesn't let you filter to find apps using specific permissions. You have to just go through every single app manually. XPrivacy does allow you to filter/search.